# PHP7.2 install on Debian 9 (stretch) fails during package configuration

Tags: php, debian, installation, stretch

I hope I'm in the right place.

I'm running a *fresh* Debian 9 (stretch) system. I'm trying to install PHP7.2 (from Ondřej Surý repository). I did the requisite `sudo apt-get update` before beginning. I then followed the instructions on [Christopher Shaw's site](https://www.chris-shaw.com/blog/installing-php-7.2-on-debian-8-jessie-and-debian-9-stretch):

```
    sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
    sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
    echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

I then did another `sudo apt-get update`  After that, I proceeded to the meat of things: `sudo apt-get install php7.2` Then the problems started. Here's the output:

```
    (( -- successful stuff snipped -- ))
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
    Setting up php7.2-common (7.2.7-1+0~20180622080745.23+stretch~1.gbpfd8e2e) ...
    touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/php/modules/7.2/apache2/enabled_by_maint/calendar': No such file or directory
    dpkg: error processing package php7.2-common (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.2-readline:
     php7.2-readline depends on php7.2-common (= 7.2.7-1+0~20180622080745.23+stretch~1.gbpfd8e2e); however:
      Package php7.2-common is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package php7.2-readline (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.2:
     php7.2 depends on php7.2-common; however:
      Package php7.2-common is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package php7.2 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.2-cli:
     php7.2-cli depends on php7.2-common (= 7.2.7-1+0~20180622080745.23+stretch~1.gbpfd8e2e); however:
      Package php7.2-common is not configured yet.
     php7.2-cli depends on php7.2-readline; however:
      Package php7.2-readline is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package php7.2-cli (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.2-json:
     php7.2-json depends on php7.2-common (= 7.2.7-1+0~20180622080745.23+stretch~1.gbpfd8e2e); however:
      Package php7.2-common is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package php7.2-json (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.2:
     libapache2-mod-php7.2 depends on php7.2-cli; however:
      Package php7.2-cli is not configured yet.
     libapache2-mod-php7.2 depends on php7.2-common (= 7.2.7-1+0~20180622080745.23+stretch~1.gbpfd8e2e); however:
      Package php7.2-common is not configured yet.
     libapache2-mod-php7.2 depends on php7.2-json; however:
      Package php7.2-json is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.2 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.2-opcache:
     php7.2-opcache depends on php7.2-common (= 7.2.7-1+0~20180622080745.23+stretch~1.gbpfd8e2e); however:
      Package php7.2-common is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package php7.2-opcache (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     php7.2-common
     php7.2-readline
     php7.2
     php7.2-cli
     php7.2-json
     libapache2-mod-php7.2
     php7.2-opcache
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    ~$
```

I searched and searched and searched and found *nothing* regarding this issue. After thrashing for almost an hour, I tried ..

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get autoclean
    sudo apt-get clean
    sudo apt-get autoremove
```

... then tried the process again. No joy.

I'm seriously dead in the water and completely at a loss. Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong or what I may try next?

Thanks!

Comment: The only crucial info there is `touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/php/modules/7.2/apache2/enabled_by_maint/calendar': No such file or directory`. So tell us more about the existing folder structure there.

Comment: All I can tell you is that it's a fresh Debian 9 install. I've create no unusual or custom directories. Up to this point, the only other things I've installed were `linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//')` `nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver` `sudo` `vim-gui-common` `vim-runtime` `cifs-utils` `smbclient` `samba` `lshw` `curl` and `rsync` -- *that's it*.

Of that directory with the failed `touch`, only this much of the path exists: `/var/lib/php/modules/7.2` ... and that's only after attempting my PHP7.2 install. Before the attempt, only `/var/lib` existed.

Comment: Well, create the missing directory section?